# Faster way to read file than boost::file_mapping?

Tags: c++, windows, file, memory, io

I'm writing a latency-sensitive app which reads a text file upon initialisation. I have profiled and re-written all my algorithms such that 85% of my execution time is from the lines:

```
boost::interprocess::file_mapping file(Path, read_only);
boost::interprocess::mapped_region data(file, read_only);
```

I am writing this on windows- is there any faster way to map a file into memory? Portability is not a concern.

Comment: Keep in mind that disk I/O is many orders of magnitude slower than memory I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the native functions of Win32, but I think you won't save alot, because boost will not add alot of overhead:

```
OFSTRUCT ofStruct;
ofStruct.cBytes=sizeof (OFSTRUCT);
HANDLE file=(HANDLE)OpenFile(fileName, &ofStruct, OF_READ); 
if (file==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
  handle errors
else {
  HANDLE map=CreateFileMapping(file, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
  if (map==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    handle errors
  else {
    const char *p=(const char *)MapViewOfFile(map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));
    if (p) {
      // enjoy using p to read access file contents.
    }
    // close all that handles now...
  }
```

Comment: not only this, but if OP uses boost extensively, he will have to code up all the boilerplate code that boost already implements to interface his boost based code with its winapi data loading routines.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dropping the idea of file mapping.

FM is a complicated construct and adds some overhead. Plain cached read also involves non-trivial interaction with the physical device. You could do unbuffered reads. Probably the next thing to ask is what kind of IO you actually want - how big is the file? is it sequential? Is it on the network? Do you have a choice of hardware, or is it on the customers' machine?

Comment: The files are tiny, which is why I read them into memory. Would you be able to give an example of the unbuffered approach? I just need to read the files as fast as possible.

Comment: If the files are tiny, there is even more reason to avoid mapping to memory. Refer to CreateFile documentation and the NO_BUFFERING flags part.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are small, just open and read them into memory using standard Win32 CreateFile()/ReadFile() APIs.

If you're consuming each file sequentially (or could arrange your code in such a way that you do), you should specify FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN.  This is a hint for the file/caching subsystem to read-ahead aggressively.  For small files, the file might be read into cache before your first call to ReadFile() is issued.

**Edit**: As requested, Here's a snippet that illustrates reading the contents of a file into a vector of bytes using the Win32 API:

```
void ReadFileIntoBuffer( const std::wstring& fileName, std::vector< uint8_t >& output )
{
    HANDLE hFile( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE );
    try 
    {
        // Open the file.
        hFile = CreateFile( filename.c_str(), 
                                 GENERIC_READ,
                                 FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                 NULL,
                                 OPEN_EXISTING, 
                                 FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                                 NULL );
        if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile )
            throw std::runtime_error( "Failed to open file." );

        // Fetch size
        LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;
        if( !GetFileSizeEx( hFile, &fileSize ) );
            throw std::runtime_error( "GetFileSizeEx() failed." );

        // Resize output buffer.
        output.resize( fileSize.LowPart );

        // Read the file contents.
        ULONG bytesRead;
        if( !ReadFile( hFile, &output[0], fileSize.LowPart, &bytesRead, NULL ) )
            throw std::runtime_error( "ReadFile() failed." );

        // Recover resources.
        CloseHandle( hFile );
    }
    catch( std::exception& ) 
    {
        // Dump the error.
        std::cout << e.what() << " GetLastError() = " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        // Recover resources.
        if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile )
            CloseHandle( hFile );

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I trouble you for a snippet? Not sure I totally understand

Comment: Note that if the files are really tiny, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN may not make any difference -- it tells the cache to do more read-ahead, but for a tiny file, the normal read-ahead may well read the whole file.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - You are correct - tiny files (less than a few cache pages) will usually be read in their entirety.  In general, in cases like this, when you have knowledge of your file access patterns, it is good practice to provide this data to the operating system.